# Read text value from span tag

Tags: ruby, xpath, cucumber, capybara, capybara-webkit

I need to read text value from span tag inside a selected radio button using capyvara

I have a list  of `radio button` followed by text and its count in brackets.

For eg: radiobutton with `Thank You(82)`
What I want is to read the selected radio button count 82 inside bracket.

I used following code..but it is not working

```
value=page.find(".cardFilterItemSelection[checked='checked'] + span.itemCount").text
```

and tried using Xpath but not getting anything

```
 value=page.find(:xpath,"//input[@class = 'cardFilterItemSelection' and @checked = 'checked']/span[@class = 'itemCount']/text()")
```

How it is possible?

```html
<label id="thankyou_label" for="thankyou_radio" class="itemName radio">
  <input checked="checked" tagtype="Occasion" value="Thank You" id="thankyou_radio" name="occasionGroup" class="cardFilterItemSelection" type="radio">
  <span class="occasion_display_name">
    Thank You 
  </span>
  <span class="itemCount">
    (82)
  </span>
</label>

<label id="spring_label" class="itemName radio" for="spring_radio">
  <input id="spring_radio" class="cardFilterItemSelection" type="radio" name="occasionGroup" value="Spring" tagtype="Occasion">
  <span class="occasion_display_name">
    Spring 
  </span>
  <span class="itemCount">
    (0)
  </span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you were on the right track. But you should have query not for the text node contained by span, but for the span itself and use XPath [axes](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp)

```
span = page.find(:xpath,"//input[@class = 'cardFilterItemSelection' and @checked = 'checked']/following-sibling::span[@class = 'itemCount']")
value = span.text
```

However I personally find css selectors more readable (unless you need to make complex query)

```
span = page.find(:css, 'input.cardFilterItemSelection[checked=checked] ~ span.itemCount')
value = span.text
```